Please welcome Spevacus and rene to the Meta Stack Exchange moderators team!
After discussing it with the Meta Stack Exchange mods and some potential candidates, we are excited to welcome Spevacus and rene to the MSE moderation team. As with previous moderator appointments on MSE, they have been prominent contributors to the network for quite some time and are natural additions to the team. We found the two of them to be exemplary leaders around the network and fair and down-to-earth individuals.
To be eligible to moderate MSE, we considered individuals the CM team believed might be a good addition based on their history as moderators or their contributions across the network. We expect both of them will do an excellent job contributing to the moderation of MSE.
Please feel free to share your best celebratory memes or words of inspiration to kick-start their tenure.

How many moderators does this site expect to have in general?

As many as needed. There's a few uh... unusual aspects to moderating here, and there's times when you need ALL THE MODS.

Congrats and welcome, Spevacus and rene! I know you'll both do great.

When I was reached out to about becoming a moderator here, I was quite surprised. All previous Meta SE moderators were already established moderators elsewhere. I've never been a moderator on the network. Having the confidence of my new colleagues to take up a diamond here despite that is amazing. I sincerely hope to live up to that sentiment. I know that, while I have been around for a little bit now, I still have much to learn from all of you.
The core community here at Meta SE is pretty self-sufficient. We all manage the stream of ill-fitting content here quite well... But Meta SE serves as one of the primary places for the company to communicate with the community. We've had to have some tough conversations in the past, where a lot of care and discretion was needed on the part of the moderator team here. I expect that we'll have to have more of those tough conversations in the future. It's in those moments that I hope to best serve you all, and earn the same trust that my new colleagues earned a long time ago. The most engaged of us are in-tune with the mixed feelings we may or may not have at the moment. My hope is that things will improve, and I'll do everything I can to help work towards that end, in whatever capacity I'm able.
I am, as always, happy to help out with the ordinary janitorial tasks we're familiar with here, and if there are larger curation tasks that would benefit from a diamond, sign me up. Don't be afraid to call me out if I mess up, in whatever avenues you feel appropriate. I firmly believe in the concepts of transparency and open communication when it comes to moderation. That's something I picked up fighting spam with those awesome Charcoal folks (come say hi!), and it's not something I'm interested in changing my mind on. I'm certain to get it wrong at some point, and I'll always be willing to chat about it.
With all that out of the way... Thank you all so much for your support! Thanks, of course, to rene for being willing to jump into this with me, and to the existing moderators and CM team for their trust in me. These folks always give us their best, even when we're not always thankful for it. You guys are awesome, and I'm immensely grateful for the chance to work with you.

Brazilian greetings to the two new members of the MSE Moderator team.
Success on this journey to rene◆ and Spevacus◆. 

PS: Now, as MSE moderators, are you going to fix Stack Snippets, which doesn't work properly with touchscreen devices?(just kidding, but not really)

If being a MSE moderator means things will be fixed, I'd not have hung up my hat :D

I've only got a diamond, not the keys to the liquor cabinet ...

@rene, I could swore that the mod position comes with access to the SE minibar. :P

@AugustoVasques sadly only staff can, and even then, only specific staff can fix specific things. :)

Guys, I know the Mod duties and I know that diamond privileges go only slightly beyond the privileges of an Trusted User. Sorry for any confusion, although the joke refers to mods, the reminder about the stack snippet are for those responsible staff.

I'm holding the PR that fixes AllTheThings (tm) hostage until I get my SE mod merch :)

@Spe what about a golden cage? Right from their cellar?

Congratulations and welcome, Spevacus and rene. I hope that two of you can moderate this site well with other moderators. It maybe not easy to balance this voluntary job with real life, but I believe the two of you can do it.

Congratulations and I hope and know you two will make great moderators.

why do you have to hope if you know?

@starball hoping in something you know to be true is just an expression of faith. :)

... and I have faith in both Spevacus and rene, even though the latter still owes me a Christmas Pudding.
